# HTML input field dynamic "placeholder"

Tags: html, date, input, placeholder

I have a rather stupid question, but I would like some input on the issue.

On some websites you have a date input field, which has a placeholder in the form of mm/dd/yyyy.

However, when you start typing, the characters are getting replaced one by one, like 02/3d/yyyy.

So its not a placeholder but some sort of dynamic input already. My question is, how is this generated? Is this a javascript library (jquery, angularjs etc.) or any other feature im not aware of?

Thanks for your help, I tried finding appropriate code online but nothing did the function described above.

I mean of course you could program in JS an event listener on keypress, and depending on the input you adjust the field accordingly, but I wonder if there is an easier way to do so!

Comment: Check out masked-textboxes

Comment: https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/

Answer (score 0):

You can create the mask by following this guide: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask